# Trigonometric equations of the form $a \cdot \sin(x + k) = b \cdot \cos(x - k)$

Tags: trigonometry

Quite straightforward question, given a trigonometric equation $a \cdot \sin (x + k) = b \cdot \cos( x - k )$ how can one find the solution.
e. g. $3 \cdot \sin(x + π/6) = 2 \cdot \cos( x - π/6 )$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**.  Use the sine-of-a-sum and cosine-of-a-sum formulae to expand, collect terms to get
$$A\sin x+B\cos x=0$$
for some constants $A,B$.  Rearranging,
$$\tan x=-\frac BA\ .$$
You will have to be careful if any coefficients turn out to be zero.  I'm sure you can fill in the details for yourself.